# How the program runs when I use await in object literal?

Tags: javascript, async-await, object-literal, ecma

When I write a function that returns an object, but each values of the object are constructed by resolving promises, what will I obtain at the end? I mean, what will be types of object's values?

```js
async foo() {
    return {
        p1: await fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees') // FETCH REQUEST,
        p2: await fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees') // FETCH REQUEST
    }
}
```

and for such a flow, will `p2` be resolved after `p1`? Does this code works as the same as below example:

```js
async foo() {
    const p1 = await fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees') // FETCH REQUEST
    const p2 = await fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees') // FETCH REQUEST
    return {
        p1,
        p2
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I am trying to illustrate. I have edited my question, sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: `await FETCH REQUEST` is not valid javascript, so we have no way of telling you what the return type will be

Comment: @Jamiec thank you for your extremely helpful reply (!) I am just trying to learn something and you points out a meaningless point. Don't you really understand why I asked? Ok, I will try to ask my question in a more clear way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for calling me out for asking you to clarify your question(!). I'll do my best to interpret what you're actually asking. I was tempted to simply delete this answer. It may or may not be helpful!

If you fake up whatever "FETCH REQUEST" is, with an `async` method which simply prints to the console when it starts, and right before it (async) resolves, you can quite clearly see that it will complete `p1` before starting `p2`. Running it a few times confirms this as the calls to `p1` and `p2` do not interleave.

```js
async function foo() {
    return {
        p1: await randomAsyncMethod("p1"),
        p2: await randomAsyncMethod("p2")
    }
}

async function randomAsyncMethod(which){
   console.log("starting",which);
   return new Promise( resolve =>  
      setTimeout( () => {
          console.log("resolving",which);
          resolve();
      }, Math.random() * 1000)
   );
}


foo();
```

Now changing that to your second example, you can see the behavior is basically the same.

```js
async function foo() {
    var p1 = await randomAsyncMethod("p1");
    var p2 = await randomAsyncMethod("p2");
    return {
        p1,
        p2 
    }
}

async function randomAsyncMethod(which){
   console.log("starting",which);
   return new Promise( resolve =>  
      setTimeout( () => {
          console.log("resolving",which);
          resolve();
      }, Math.random() * 1000)
   );
}


foo();
```

As for what your object will contain the return value of the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) method is:

> A Promise that resolves to a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object.

Comment: Thank you! I am really glad you answered my question, I couldn't think such a example, so couldn't resolve it myself. Maybe I am tired or stupid, or due to my inadequate English, idk. In any case, I am glad. Thank you again :))

Comment: @keskinsaf note to future you: If someone asks you to clarify your question, don't get defensive. It gets very tiresome trying to guess what people _actually_ mean and then getting it wrong, and going round in circles. You're welcome, glad I could help.

Comment: I didn't understand you asked me to clarify my question but I see what you mean. I will spend more effort before asking my next question :)) thank you again :))

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

> A Promise is a proxy for a value not necessarily known when the promise is created. It allows you to associate handlers with an asynchronous action's eventual success value or failure reason. This lets asynchronous methods return values like synchronous methods: instead of immediately returning the final value, the asynchronous method returns a promise to supply the value at some point in the future.

p1, and p2 return a promise in both examples.